# How to perform a filtering join with fixed date range in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to perform a filtering join with a fixed date range e.g. 2 days. Please see example below:

```
library(tibble)

#Create tibble1
patient_id <- c("patient1", "patient2")
laterality <- c("L", "R")
date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-24", "2010-09-24"))
tibble1 <- tibble(patient_id, laterality, date)

#Create tibble2
patient_id <- c("patient1", "patient2", "patient1", "patient1")
laterality <- c("L", "R", "R", "L")
date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-24", "2010-09-24", "2010-09-18", "2020-10-25"))
type <- c("dark", "light", "dark", "light")
tibble2 <- tibble(patient_id, laterality, date, type)

#Create output
patient_id <- c("patient1", "patient2", "patient1")
laterality <- c("L", "R", "L")
date <- as.Date(c("2020-10-24", "2010-09-24", "2020-10-25"))
type <- c("dark", "light", "light")
output <- tibble(patient_id, laterality, date, type)
```

I would like to filter `tibble2` using `tibble1`, with a fixed date range of +/- 2 days, which should give `output`. I have tried using semi_join but not sure how to incorporate the date range.

```
semi_join(tibble2,tibble1)
```

I have seen other solution which have separate `from` and `to` columns to define the range, but was hoping to do it with a single fixed range for all rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mutate to create the start/end values for each row then join the data

```
library(dplyr)
tibble2 %>% 
  mutate(start=date-2, end=date+2, date=NULL) %>% 
  right_join(tibble1, join_by(patient_id, laterality, between(y$date, x$start, x$end))) %>% 
  select(-start, -end)
#   patient_id laterality type  date      
#   <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <date>    
# 1 patient1   L          dark  2020-10-24
# 2 patient2   R          light 2010-09-24
# 3 patient1   L          light 2020-10-24
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't get the `right_join` to work. Is `join_by` supposed to be just `by`? And is `y` tibble1 and `x` tibble2? Even with these I can't get the `between` to work like that.

Comment: I copy/pasted your test data to get this output. Did you copy/paste but are getting a different output? This was tested with `dplyr_1.1.0`. Are you using a different version of `dplyr`? See the `?join_by` help page; it is different than `by=`. The `x` and `y` names are used by `join_by` to indicate the left and right tables in the join.

Comment: Sorry it was a version issue! Could I please check - what made you choose a `right_join` in this case? For the minimal example it doesn't matter but in my data there are  duplicate keys in `tibble2` but not in `tibble1`. I want the output to keep all duplicate keys  as long as they appear once in `tibble1`. For this, I thought it's better to use a `semi_join`?

Comment: I used `right_join` because I assumed you wanted to keep all the data from `tibble1` but since I had to mutate `tibble2` first, I needed on the right. You can use which every join is more appropriate for you. `join_by` should work with them all.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want the range to be specified by the max and min dates in tibble1?

You can achieve such result using dplyr::filter() and dplyr::between():

```
filter(tibble2, between(date,
                        min(tibble1$date) - 2, 
                        max(tibble1$date) + 2))
```